# Вывод данных из БД в JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Помогите кто-нибудь додуматься. Ситуация такая:

Есть какая-нибудь страница (допустим index.jsp), на которой должны выводить блоки с информацией. Эту информацию мы должны подгружать из БД, через Java Servlet. Но при этом я не хочу нажимать на какие-нибудь кнопки для отправки POST запроса, что вытащить эти данные. Хотелось бы чтобы когда заходишь на страницу, инфа сама вытаскивалась из БД  и выводилась в jsp. При этом эта же инфа может выводит и в других страница jsp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно данные получать из сервлета, но страницу (jsp) нужно открывать через `Servlet`, а все данные добавлять в запрос. На jsp-странице будет доступ к этой переменной.

```
        List<Map> usersList = User.findAll();
        request.setAttribute("list", usersList);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Если jsp страница открывается напрямую, то можете использовать [java bean](http://www.java2ee.ru/jsp/useBean.html).

```
<jsp:useBean id="users" class="bean.Users" scope="request" ></jsp:useBean>
....
<% List users = users.findAll(); %>
```

Или вы можете подгружать информацию с помощью JavaScript (`ajax`), отправляя запросы при загрузке страницы, повесив событие при загрузке документа (не нажимая ни на какие кнопки).

А как получать данные именно из БД, то это не много другой вопрос, и все засивит от самой БД.